# Unable to access local variables in for, php

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I have a little piece of code that seems to be working fine and dandy, but i cant acces the local variable from the for function. I also tried it with while and still no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
$numbers = array(57, 70, 83, 96, 109, 122, 135);

$content = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= count($numbers)-1; $i++){

    if(!in_array(getGroupAttributes($numbers[$i]), $content)){
        $attr = getGroupAttributes($numbers[$i]);
        $content = array_merge($content, getGroupAttributes($numbers[$i]));
        var_dump($content);
    }

}
```

The content array is always empty. The $numbers array seems to be accesible.

Comment: What does `var_dump(getGroupAttributes($numbers[$i]));` return ?

Comment: Try `$content = array();` instead of `$content = [];`

Comment: what does your `getGroupAttributes()` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for sure not a problem of accessing the local variable `$numbers` or `$content` but the function `getGroupAttributes()` returning an empty array or maybe nothing at all (do you have warnings and notices enabled?)

Comment: The getGroupAttributes works fine. But it does retrun an empty array if the particular attribute doesnt exist.... I guess i make a check for the empty ones...

Comment: impossible. just check your `getGroupAttributes()` to return an array with content then it will work.

Comment: Thanks so much, it did help. I havent thought that empty array would be a problem. Thanks again.